# Conditional regex to match timestamps that are not inside of quotes

Tags: regex

I just want to match time stamps that are not inside of quotes:

> 03:00
>
> 2:00
>
> 10:00
>
> 03:00
>
> 1:04:01
>
> 01:04:01

And not these ones:

> "2:00"
>
> "10:00"
>
> "01:04:01"

I have the expression:

```
(?!["'])\b(\d{1,2}:\d{2})(?::\d{2})?\b(?!["'])
```

It's working fine but it should not select this one "01:04:01"

Here is i am working https://regex101.com/r/vS2sT9/4

Comment: You're trying to ignore times that are in quotes?

Comment: If you're using PCRE/PHP you can also [`(*SKIP)(*F)` what's inside quotes](https://regex101.com/r/kU1xZ4/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your initial regular expression, one option is to change the negative lookahead to optionally match digit/colon character(s) until the quote: `(?![:\d]*["'])`.

[**Updated Example**](https://regex101.com/r/yY2kP4/1)

```
\b(?:(\d{1,2}:\d{2})(?::\d{2})?)(?![:\d]*["'])\b
```

You could also change it to `(?!(?::\d+)?["'])` in order to optionally match one colon followed by one or more digits:

[**Updated Example**](https://regex101.com/r/aJ2pQ6/1)

```
\b(?:(\d{1,2}:\d{2})(?::\d{2})?)(?!(?::\d+)?["'])\b
```

---

However, an alternative option that may actually be better would be to use an alternation in order to match strings between quotes and then you can use a capturing group to capture the actual dates:

[**Updated Example**](https://regex101.com/r/rG6lV7/1) - The dates are in the first capturing group

```
["'].*?["']|\b(?:(\d{1,2}:\d{2})(?::\d{2})?)\b
```

---

You can also use a back-reference in order to close the quote:

[**Updated Example**](https://regex101.com/r/wP9nR4/1) - Now the dates are in the second capturing group since the back-referenced quote is in the first capturing group.

```
(["']).*?\1|\b(?:(\d{1,2}:\d{2})(?::\d{2})?)\b
```